# Remove \part bookmark

Tags: bookmarks

I just have a text divided in two parts.
I used the bookmark package, and in the pdf file the bookmarks are shown.
Since I consider the `\part` bookmark nonsense, I wanted shown just the bookmarks of the lower levels (`\chapter`, `\section`, etc. ...). 
How can I do this?
P:S: I also used the hyperref package, maybe is in conflict with that?

Comment: Untested: `\usepackage[level=chapter]{bookmark}`

Comment: It doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `toclevel@part` is shifted downwards to some value not normally used by bookmarks, it won't be shown at all.

However, the chapter bookmarks are nevertheless shown indented in the tree. This can be prevented using `\bookmarksetup{level=part}`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\toclevel@part}{10}
\makeatother
\bookmarksetup{level=part}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{One}
\chapter{foo}

\chapter{Two}

\part{Second}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved, bookmarks package automatic disable option of hyperref package regarding bookmarks.
The option are differents according which package you're using.
If you use bookmark package you should write the option

```
\usepackage[open, openlevel=0]{bookmarks}
```

To show just the \part and the \chapter bookmarks at the opening.
If the level is set to 1 it would show also show all the \section.
Bookmarks not removed at all, but it's however useful.
According to Chris's answer, you can cancel from "makeatletter" to "\bookmarksetup{level=part}" and insert my option, it's the same (I tried kind randomised, but it worked!)